# Kivy for data visualisation

Tags: plot, flask, visualization, kivy

I want to make an application using kivy . The main requirement of my project is to display interactive plots (supporting zooming,displaying coordinates when hovered over the data point etc ) . Earlier I was using Flask framework and I was able to accomplish this using various plotting libraries like Plotly . Can some one please guide me if some plotting library exists for kivy also , so that I can have interactive graphs .

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have ediited my question

Comment: Please note that this is a question and answer site, not a
code writing service. If you [edit] your question to
describe what you have tried so far and where you are stuck,
then we can try to help with specific problems. You should
also read [ask].

Comment: Did you manage to get the interactive plot to work within kivy?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are three options I can think of. None are as mature as the web options.

- The [Matplotlib integration widget](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.matplotlib) lets you display matplotlib plots. Matplotlib isn't so amazing at animation and this is probably slow anyway compared to many alternatives, and especially given how the kivy view is made.
- The [Graph](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.graph) widget in the Kivy garden. This is a pure-Kivy solution, but doesn't implement many different plot attributes and isn't particularly actively maintained, partly in favour of the matplotlib solution.
- You can in principle use an opengl library such as Vispy in combination with Kivy, but this would need some interoperation code and I'm not aware of anyone having done it.